# XPath "Counter" expression is not returning a valid number

Tags: xml, xpath, counter, infopath2010

Is there a way to modify the following XPath expression to return the number of previous "like" elements? I need a relative count of the number of like nodes in a given branch (I think it's a branch...) This is being used in MS InfoPath:

`count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1`

I believe that the structure of my sample XML prevents this from behaving as intended. You will note that all the "Count" values in my XML have the number **1**. The `DateRepeaterCounter` value should reset in a new `MasterRepeater` node and the `MasterRepeaterCounter` should reflect the overall number of `MasterRepeater` nodes.

I have yet to overcome the learning curve with XPath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.25" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\e1d38b31bb224d94\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-09-07T14:19:10" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:PrimarySection>
    <my:MasterRepeater>
        <my:MasterRepeaterCounter>1</my:MasterRepeaterCounter>
        <my:DateSection>
            <my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-12</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater>
            <my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-13</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater>
            <my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-14</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater>
            </my:DateSection>
    </my:MasterRepeater>
    <my:MasterRepeater>
        <my:MasterRepeaterCounter>1</my:MasterRepeaterCounter>
        <my:DateSection>
            <my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-15</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater>
            <my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-16</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater><my:DateRepeater>
                <my:Date>2012-09-17</my:Date>
                <my:DateRepeaterCounter>1</my:DateRepeaterCounter>
            </my:DateRepeater>
    </my:DateSection>
    </my:MasterRepeater>
</my:PrimarySection>
</my:myFields>
```

---

**EDIT & ANSWER**

InfoPath was messing up the expression somehow... After entering the expression in one field and then copying it into another it stopped working correctly. Upon re-entering the epxression as formatted above, it resolved the issue. I will self answer when StackOverflow allows it. Thanks!

Comment: From which node do you want to start? What nodes do you want to count? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The listed XPath expression exists in every node with the word "Counter" in its name. What you see in the XML is the result (the current result) of this expression. I *guess* that means it has to count from its own location back, and any node with the word 'counter' in the name must contain this counter. Apologies for being vague, I'm slowly learning how to ask the right questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll self answer this one. It was an InfoPath issue, not an XPath issue. The XPath expression I have works great, it's just that InfoPath wasn't interpreting it correctly... Like somehow the expression just got gooned up along the way. When I re-entered it as it was formatted originally: `count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1` it started working excellently. So... Thanks again Microsoft for driving me crazy.

Comment: If you found out the solution yourself you can write an answer (not just a comment) and also accept it (time restrictions may apply) so your question won't popup as unanswered anymore. Good luck with the further x-pathing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll self answer this one as it turned out to be an InfoPath issue and not an XPath issue. InfoPath was messing up the expression somehow... After entering the expression in one field and then copying it into another it stopped working correctly. Upon re-entering the epxression as formatted above, it resolved the issue. Thanks for all your help!